# MongooseJS: Prevent .populate() from setting field to NULL?

Tags: mongoose

I have a Mongoose model with a property which references another model (i.e., a document in a separate collection). The referenced document doesn't always exist (e.g., it was deleted). In this scenario, if I call model.someProp.populate(), model.someProp is set to NULL.

Is it possible to modify .populate()'s behavior such that, if no referencing document can be found, you retain the original field value instead of it being set to NULL?

Comment: Also interested! I just found that you can test FIRST if the referenceId is not null and THEN try to populate, if after that is null, then we have a broken link!